# Dictionary error while removing two time the same index

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've a problem with a dictionary. Like it's said in the title, I'm getting an error everytime I'm trying to delete the same index two time in a row.

Id i have a dictionary of 60 entries, and I remove the entry 0, the entry 1 should became entry 0, the 2 entry 1,... So i should be able the delete the entry 0 another time, no ?

Maybe I'm wrong, and you can tell me how does it work ?

ps:I'm using the remove() function.

```
        foreach (var item in classBoxList)
        {
            uint classId = 0;
            bool contain = false;
            uint index = 0;
            uint i = 0;

            foreach (var charClass in DbcStores.ChrClasses.Records)
            {
                if (charClass.Name.String == item.Name)
                    classId = charClass.ClassId;
            }

            CharBaseInfoEntry charClassRace = new CharBaseInfoEntry() { RaceId = (byte)raceId, ClasseId = (byte)classId };

            foreach (var t in DbcStores.CharBaseInfo.Records)
            {
                if (t.ClasseId == classId && t.RaceId == raceId)
                {
                    contain = true;
                    index = i;
                }

                i++;
            }

            if (contain)
            {
                if (item.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    //remove the race/class entry
                    MessageBox.Show(index+" -- "+ DbcStores.CharBaseInfo.Records.Count.ToString());
                    DbcStores.CharBaseInfo.RemoveEntry(index);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (item.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    //add the new race/class entry
                    DbcStores.CharBaseInfo.AddEntry(DbcStores.CharBaseInfo.MaxKey + 1, charClassRace);
                }
            }
        }


    public void RemoveEntry(uint id)
    {
        if (!mRecords.ContainsKey(id))
            throw new Exception("Cette clé n'existe pas !");

        IsEdited = true;
        mRecords.Remove(id);
    }
```

Comment: It is better if you show the failing code.

Comment: What are you trying to do? emptying the dictionary?

Comment: No, but the user should be able to remove everything he want

Comment: where is the Dictionary ?

Comment: `Id i have a dictionary of 60 entries, and I remove the entry 0, the entry 1 should became entry 0, the 2 entry 1,... So i should be able the delete the entry 0 another time, no ?` No, `Dictionay` doesn't work in this manner.

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler In another file, i added the removeEntry function.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Thanks, so what can i do to make it work ? Sorting everything ?

Comment: Why do need to change the ID anyway? Do you need a specific order starting at `0`? We could suggest a fitting solution when we knew what you're trying to achieve

Comment: So, I have some comboBox with true/false, loaded from the dictionary. If the user modify some of them on false then save, i want the associated value to be removed from the dictionnary.

Comment: Still see no need to change all the IDs

Comment: I don't want to change all the ID, just to find the way to achieve that. I was wrong on how the dictionary work.

Comment: The order of things in a Dictionary is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not removing the entry given some **index** but the entry which has the given **key**

That, and in a Dictionary a key is unique so trying to remove two times in a row the same key is a nonsense (unless re-added somewhere else in the meantime)

Comment: And is there a way to got the key of something whe know ?

Comment: @SiveurWesttunger you mean getting a key given some value ?

Comment: Yes, since I have the value I want to remove, maybe I could get the key from her and then remove with this key.

Comment: A dictionary isn't meant to be used that way but rather the opposite use the key to access quickly and simply to the value. There is nothing preventing multiple keys to have the same value so from a given value you can't get *it's key*. you could get some keys (plural) but tha means looping the whole dict to check them and store the keys (because as already said a dict isn't meant to be manipulated this way)

Comment: Thank you, i'll maybe use something else than a dictionary then. Anyway i'll do more research.

Answer (score 0):

The second time you remove the index the excpetion is thrown , remove the throw exception

```
public void RemoveEntry(uint id)
{

    IsEdited = true;
    mRecords.Remove(id);
}
```

and regarding your second , request of

> I remove the entry 0, the
>   entry 1 should became entry 0, the 2 entry 1

that is not done by `Dictionray`, what may do something slimier is `SortedDictionay` which can be sorted by items keys. so in order to access the first item ,( note the first item is the one with the lowest key).

For example :

```
var dic = new SortedDictionay<int,string>();
dic.Add(0,"First Item");
dic.Add(1,"Second Item");

dic.Items.First(); // returns first item
dic.Remove(0);
dic.Items.First(); // returns second item
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to know you could do this, have a look at this:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 3, "3" },
    { 0, "0" },
    { 1, "1" },
    { 2, "2" }
};

// remove something
d.Remove(1);

// rebuilt the dictionary
d = d.OrderBy(x => x.Key)
     .Select((o, i) => new { i, o.Value })
     .ToDictionary(t => t.i, t => t.Value);

// result
// { 0, "0" },
// { 1, "2" },
// { 2, "3" },
```